# R: Latex in Title Names of Charts, Plots, Histograms, etc

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to title a histogram in R Markdown with a title involving Latex. However, I can't get it to work. Here is my format in code chunk for R Mark down:

```
hist(X, freq = FALSE,  breaks = 115, main="Blah Blah $MATH$")
hist(X, freq = FALSE, breaks = 100, main="Blah Blah $MATH$")
```

Any recommendations ?

Answer (score 2):

In the context of R Markdown documents, I would actually strongly urge you to use figure captions rather than plot titles, like so:

````r
---
title: "Stack Overflow Answer"
author: "duckmayr"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r histogram, fig.cap="Blah Blah $\\mathcal{MATH}$"}
hist(islands, main = "")
```
````

[image]

### Update: Multiple histograms

You can use subfigures, which is the normal LaTeX way.
Then you'll use the `fig.subcap` chunk option rather than `fig.cap`:

````
title: "Stack Overflow Answer"
author: "duckmayr"
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{subcaption}
output: pdf_document
---

```{r histogram, fig.cap="Histograms", fig.subcap=c("Blah Blah $\\mathcal{MATH}$ (islands)", "Blah Blah $\\mathcal{MATH}$ (linx)"), out.width="45%"}
hist(islands, main = "")
hist(lynx, main = "")
```
````

[image]

Comment: this is very helpful but what do I do if I have several side by side histograms?

Comment: @PortMadeleineCrumpet use the `fig.subcap` chunk option. See https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#plots for details

Comment: @PortMadeleineCrumpet I updated the answer to illustrate this

Answer (score 0):

You can add (limited) latex with `latex2exp`

```
 install.packages("latex2exp")
```

You could use it like this:

```
library("latex2exp")
hist(islands, main =TeX('$\\alpha^5 - \\beta$'))
```

Which would look like:
[image]

Best is you take a look at the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/latex2exp/vignettes/using-latex2exp.html) page  what kind of Latex formatting is possible with the package.

Comment: Can you combine it with standard text or would you have to use the latex command \text{blah blah}?

Comment: Yes you somehow can, try: hist(islands, main =TeX('hello portmadeleine upvote my answer: $\\alpha^5 - \\beta$'))